# Retrieving mail iD in "To" and comparing with user input in javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using Javamail to get some email data. I take user input as email id, imap address and password and connect to the imap. Then i monitor emails of the inbox and find out whether this person was in To or Cc.

EmailId input is like this -

> john.doe@xyz.com

but when i read mails and get the person's in "To", i get the person's email id as

> John Doe [john.doe@xyz.com]

So now while comparing the email ids i get this false every time. Is there any standard followed to use certain name alias along with the email id? i am asking this so that a fix could work with any imap. 
Or is there any method in javamail which gets just the emailid omitting this name alias?

Comment: Can you provide some code where you are experiencing the problem? There are many ways to come up with a solution to this problem, even from the [API](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JavaMail `InternetAddress` class to parse that string and give you an `InternetAddress` instance from which you can use `getAddress` to get the address string.  Something like this:

```
InternetAddress addr = new InternetAddress("John Doe [john.doe@xyz.com]");
String justTheEmail = addr.getAddress();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html